# Maven build project using own script

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have many modules Maven project. Because of external Tool which generate classes and configuration files I need to use maven-exec-plugin running after "mvn compile" and before "mvn package". In case of using that Tool I had to prepare bat file which built all modules separatly.

And now is the problem - after removing m2`s folder (local repository of Maven) i can`t build any of modules because of exception. It says that couldnt not resolve dependencies for project (no pom.xml file in that repository).

I need a solution that install or overwrite main pom.xml file for project in m2 maven local repository every time when I build any of modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pom` file with artifact (created during `package` phase) are installed to local repository
during install `phase`.
You can execute

```
mvn install
```

to install all pom's (and attached artifacts) to local repository.

You can install only parent pom with `-N` option

```
mvn -N install
```